# Every possible combination of lists in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get possible combinations of two sets of lists in google earth engine, but my code did not works.

```
var Per1= ee.Array([[0.1,0.5,0.8],[0.4,0.5,0.2]])
var pre = PercFin1.toList()

var CC=ee.List([1,2,3]);

var ZZ = pre.map(function(hh){
var Per11 = ee.List(pre).get(hh);
var out = CC.zip(Per11);
return out;
});
print (ZZ)
```

The error I get is:

*List.get, argument 'index': Invalid type. Expected: Integer. Actual: List.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want, but it looks like you've got the right idea but made an incidental mistake: `hh` is not an index into `pre` but an element of it.

I modified and simplified the last part of your code (along with changing `PercFin1` to `Per1`, which I assume was a typo):

```
var ZZ = pre.map(function(hh){
  return CC.zip(hh);
});
print(ZZ);
```

The result of this is

```
[
  [[1,0.1],[2,0.5],[3,0.8]],
  [[1,0.4],[2,0.5],[3,0.2]]
]
```

which is what I understand you want — each row in `Per1` individually zipped with `CC`.